# Multiple AsyncImage seems to affect each other unexpectedly

Tags: swiftui

I have a button that fetches for 3 images and send them to 3 AsyncImages like this

```
                     LargeButton(title: "Generate",
                                disabled: isFetchingImage,
                                backgroundColor: Color.blue,
                                foregroundColor: Color.white) {
                        focusedField = nil
                        Task {
                            fetching1 = true
                            let getURL = try await networkFetch1()
                            fetching1 = false
                            imageURL1 = getURL ?? ""
                        }
                        Task {
                            fetching2 = true
                            let getURL = try await networkFetch2()
                            fetching2 = false
                            imageURL2 = getURL ?? ""
                        }
                        Task {
                            fetching3 = true
                            let getURL = try await networkFetch3()
                            fetching3 = false
                            imageURL3 = getURL ?? ""
                        }
                    }
```

And then somewhere I have 3 AyncImages

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: imageURL)) { phase in
            if fetching {
                ProgressView()
            } else if let image = phase.image {
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            } else if phase.error != nil {
                Text("There was an error loading the image.")
            } else {
                Image("SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
        }
```

States as follows:

```
@State private var fetching1: Bool = false
    @State private var fetching2: Bool = false
    @State private var fetching3: Bool = false
    
    @State private var imageURL1: String = ""
    @State private var imageURL2: String = ""
    @State private var imageURL3: String = ""
```

For some reason when the button is pressed, all 3 AsyncImages will show the ProgressView.

But as soon as 1 image is fetched from the network, the other AsyncImages stops showing ProgressView and instead just disappears.

Why is that?

Comment: These three Tasks are called synchronously. Use `Task.detached` instead.

Comment: Are you calling the same method in each Task or is it just a placeholder?

Comment: I edited the question, changed to 3 different network calls. If they are called synchronously, why do all three PlaceHolder view show immediately after I press the button?

Comment: Your code is based on `fetching`, but your variables are `fetching1`, etc. I recommend simplifying this down to a mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Doing so may also help you find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI it's `.task(id:isFetchingImage)` not an unbounded `Task`.